# How to leave whitespace in xml element in soapUI groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I'm trying to insert nodes with whitespace values into my SoapUI request. When I try to do so, SoapUI removes the whitespace from my value, leaving me with empty tags in my xml for the request. It looks like  when I want it to look like   . I turned off "strip whitespaces" and "pretty print," but still cannot get whitespace values into my elements in the soap request. Can anyone help me figure out why this is?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It would really help us answer your question if you posted your code.  Also take a look at this: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: also show us your xml doc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responses but I unfortunately can't post any of the code or xml online. I don't know if this will help, but we're using Dynamic Values to fill the xml request fields, so it looks like this <tag>${Dynamic Values#variable}</tag>. When we put a whitespace character in for the variable value, it shows up correctly in the Dynamic Values test step of soap UI, but then the whitespace is trimmed in the actual request.

Comment: What is `Dynamic Values` in the above? a step name?

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work. I used unicode in the input csv file (\u00A0 for a space) and it was correctly interpreted by the groovy script an input into my xml request in soapUI